# Python AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'requestURL'

Tags: python, python-requests, attributes

I would like to run the code from the module requests_with_caching.py that uses the build in requests module from Python.  I have 2 py.files in the samefolder (requests_with_caching.py + test.py).  The library requests is installed.

I get an AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'requestURL'.

I don't get what I'm missing ... .

```
import requests
import json

PERMANENT_CACHE_FNAME = "permanent_cache.txt"
TEMP_CACHE_FNAME = "this_page_cache.txt"

def _write_to_file(cache, fname):
    with open(fname, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(cache, indent=2))

def _read_from_file(fname):
    try:
        with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
            res = infile.read()
            return json.loads(res)
    except:
        return {}

def add_to_cache(cache_file, cache_key, cache_value):
    temp_cache = _read_from_file(cache_file)
    temp_cache[cache_key] = cache_value
    _write_to_file(temp_cache, cache_file)

def clear_cache(cache_file=TEMP_CACHE_FNAME):
    _write_to_file({}, cache_file)

def make_cache_key(baseurl, params_d, private_keys=["api_key"]):
    """Makes a long string representing the query.
    Alphabetize the keys from the params dictionary so we get the same order each time.
    Omit keys with private info."""
    alphabetized_keys = sorted(params_d.keys())
    res = []
    for k in alphabetized_keys:
        if k not in private_keys:
            res.append("{}-{}".format(k, params_d[k]))
    return baseurl + "_".join(res)

def get(baseurl, params={}, private_keys_to_ignore=["api_key"], permanent_cache_file=PERMANENT_CACHE_FNAME, temp_cache_file=TEMP_CACHE_FNAME):
    full_url = requests.requestURL(baseurl, params)
    cache_key = make_cache_key(baseurl, params, private_keys_to_ignore)
    # Load the permanent and page-specific caches from files
    permanent_cache = _read_from_file(permanent_cache_file)
    temp_cache = _read_from_file(temp_cache_file)
    if cache_key in temp_cache:
        print("found in temp_cache")
        # make a Response object containing text from the change, and the full_url that would have been fetched
        return requests.Response(temp_cache[cache_key], full_url)
    elif cache_key in permanent_cache:
        print("found in permanent_cache")
        # make a Response object containing text from the change, and the full_url that would have been fetched
        return requests.Response(permanent_cache[cache_key], full_url)
    else:
        print("new; adding to cache")
        # actually request it
        resp = requests.get(baseurl, params)
        # save it
        add_to_cache(temp_cache_file, cache_key, resp.text)
        return resp

import requests_with_caching
# it's not found in the permanent cache
res = requests_with_caching.get("https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=happy", permanent_cache_file="datamuse_cache.txt")
print(res.text[:100])
# this time it will be found in the temporary cache
res = requests_with_caching.get("https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=happy", permanent_cache_file="datamuse_cache.txt")
# This one is in the permanent cache.
res = requests_with_caching.get("https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=funny", permanent_cache_file="datamuse_cache.txt")
```

Comment: It is `requests.get` and not `requests.requestURL` I think

Comment: If I change that attribute it passes, but has another error a couple of lines further.  The code is from Coursera.  In their Runestone environment it works.  I also found the code on some other sites: http://dizzycoding.com/requests_with_caching-function-code-answer/.

Answer (score 0):

The module `requests_with_caching.py` was written for Runestone by the University of Michigan in their Coursera course [Data Collection and Processing with Python](https://www.coursera.org/learn/data-collection-processing-python/home/info).

This module imports the `requests` module, and seems to use a special `requests` method called `requestURL()`.

The thing is, the `requests.requestURL()` method used in the `requests_with_caching` module is particular to Runestone.

In fact **the entire `requests` module was rewritten** for Runestone because Runestone can't do API requests.

Take a look at the difference between Runestone's version of `requests` found in its `src/lib`.  You will notice it's different than the `requests` module in your Python environment's site packages folder when you ran `pip install requests`.

You can view Runestone's rewritten `requests` module by running this in Runestone:

```
with open('src/lib/requests.py','r') as f:
    module = f.read()
    print(module)
```

I'd suggest looking at how the Runestone `requests.requestURL()` function was written and modify your copy of the `requests_with_caching.py` module to add this custom function.

There will be other changes to make as well to get `requests_with_caching.py` to work in your local python environment.